# pplx task from native call in JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am developing and android application where I am also using JNI for calling some native functions to interact with c++ library.

In my native function I am calling pplx task for doing parallel execution. In my current flow JavaCalls->NativeMethod->NativeMethod Creates pplx task and returns-> pplx task execute later in parallel.

In the pplx task also I am finding some class and methods.

Do I need to call AttachCurrentThread in the pplx task to get the JNIEnv for this new task  ?

If not than how do JNI will maintain the local reference handling of the object used in pplx task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we need to call the attachCurrentThread as pplx is another execution flow and it has its own stack and so does locale variable.